# How to find a cell without hyperlink in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Good day, I need you help. There is a document with 270k rows with a hyperlinks to the documents in each.  Links was created automaticaly by using script, and in some cells there are no links. How I can find the next cell in which there is no a hyperlink? Using PgDn is so slow.

Comment: How many columns are there?

Comment: @Lowpar just 1 column, 3 Sheets with 90k rows in each

Comment: Just filter on blanks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `r` the range of your cells, you could do

```
Dim cell as range
for each cell in r
    if cell.Hyperlinks.count = 0 then
      ' This cell has no hyperlink, do something...
    end if
next cell
```

Comment: Can I just find next cell without hyperlink and select it. I should make changes manualy on each cell.

Comment: Just do an `Exit For` in the `if .. end if` block. Put the code in a Sub and assign the routine to a key

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: do a `cell.select` before exiting the loop

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in various ways. I'm supposing you have data in column A. some cells are hyperlinks and some not. You need to find the ones which do not have hyperlink. 
To start with the simplest follow the below steps:

1. Select the Entire Column A (from first cell to last filled with data).
2. Right click
3. Go to the filter option and wait.
4. Modal opens with various options.
5. Select `Filter By Cell's Font Color` 

   This will do the job. Since you have 270K cells, you may face issues 'coz of slow processing. In that case either you can break your data into various sheets or come back and i'll suggest another approach.

Comment: @ZeroEight If an answer solves your query it is advisable to accept the approach followed (or easier way of doing a computed task) so as to allow other users to find relevant answers in short time. Well, I'm glad it helped. :)